# Use List<Tuple<int, int>> to return data in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Given:

```
List<int> myList;
```

If I wanted to return data where the record ID was contained in this list I would simply do:

```
var q = db.Table.Where(c=> myList.Contains(c.ID));
```

However, given:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> myList;
```

How would I write a Linq query to return records where both conditions are met?  With one data point I would write:

```
var q = db.Table.Where(c=>
            c.ID == myList.Item1
            && c.AnotherValue == myList.Item2);
```

How would I convert the above statement to work on a `List<Tuple<int, int>>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Tuple` is a structure that can't not be translated to sql by your Linq Provider. A solution could be making a switch to Linq to Objects

```
var q = db.Table.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(c=> myList.Any(tuple => c.ID == tuple.Item1 &&
                                           c.AnotherValue == tuple.Item2));
```

But the bad thing about this solution is that you're going to load all the rows from that table to filter in memory.

Another solution could be using [Linqkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/):

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Table>();

foreach (string t in myList)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(c =>c.ID == t.Item1 && c.AnotherValue == t.Item2));
}

db.Table.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

You will find more info about this last solution in this [link](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but for multiple values?  If I have a list of 100 pairs, I don't want to run a query on each one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = db.Table.AsEnumerable().Where(c => myList.Any(tuple => c.ID == tuple.Item1 &&
                                               c.AnotherValue == tuple.Item2));
```

With `Any` you can check if there is at least one element in `myList` the matches your condition.

But as @octaviocci pointed out, this is not translatable to SQL, so you would need to call `AsEnumerable()` before and do the filtering locally, which may not be what you want if there are a lot of irrelevant records.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that illustrates one approach:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("demo");
// hydrate your table here...

List<Tuple<int, int>> matches = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

Func<List<Tuple<int,int>>, DataRow, bool> RowMatches = (items, row) => {

        var rowValue1 = (int)row["Id"];
        var rowValue2 = (int)row["SomeOtherValue"];

        return items.Any(item => item.Item1 == rowValue1 && item.Item2 == rowValue2);
    };

var results = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => RowMatches(matches, r));
Console.WriteLine(results.Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> myList;

var set = new HashSet(myList);

var q = db.Table.AsEnumerable().Where(c=> set.Contains(new Tuple(c.ID, c.AnotherValue)));
```

Note that hash set is used to performance-optimize the execution of `Where` clause for large `myList`.

Comment: Won't this simply just match ANY item of set1 with ANY item of set2?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Tuple` cannot be used in `Linq to Entities`, you can try something like this:

```
List<int> items1 = myList.Select(t => t.Item1).ToList();
List<int> items2 = myList.Select(t => t.Item2).ToList();

var q = db.Table.GroupBy(m => { m.ID, m.AnotherValue })
                .Where(g => items1.Contains(g.Key.ID) && 
                            items2.Contains(g.Key.AnotherValue))
                .SelectMany(g => g);
```